AWS CDK: Received response status [FAILED] from custom resource. Message returned: Error: 'Unable to connect to the server: context deadline exceeded
I am trying to create a Kubernetes service account for S3 Access for an existing cluster.
I am using the AWS CDK as mentioned in this documentation.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_eks.ServiceAccount.html
When I use CDK deploy I am getting an error on creating the service account
Received response status [FAILED] from custom resource. Message returned: Error: 'Unable to connect to the server: context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
failed to deploy: UPDATE_FAILED (The following resource(s) failed to create: [ClusterServiceAccountmanifestServiceAccountServiceAccountResource].)
I thought this could be a vpc related issue and try pass in the vpc and security group id information but didn't sort the problem.
const cluster = eks.Cluster.fromClusterAttributes(
      this,
      "Cluster",
      {
        clusterName: ClusterName,
        openIdConnectProvider: openIdConnectProvider,
        kubectlRoleArn: clusterIamRoleArn,
        vpc,
        securityGroupIds: ['sg-xxx'],
      }
);

How can I remediate this?

Are you passing the correct VPC and SG ID (i.e. the ones that the Cluster is using)?
Can you add the code the produces the error (the service account)?
